# All files checked out - git

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I have forked one repo from github to gitlab.

which is following.

https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples

when I clone it to my PC from gitlab, it shows all files checked out.

I haven't made any change so far.

What am I doing wrong?

Updated steps.

1) I forked repo from github.

2) I imported repo in gitlab.

3) I clonned repo using "git clone Repo Name"

4) No files changed. Still all files are showing as "Deleted" to commit.

Expected output. No files should be shown as deleted (nor changed). which I haven't because I have just clonned it.

Comment: What do you mean "it shows all files checked out"? Where do you see these files? What do you expect differently?

Comment: It seems some default branch related issue. I had seen this before, but now I am not able to google it. I lost that link somewhere. This issue occurs I guess when default branch is different than the cloned one.

Comment: I still don't understand what the issue is. What is the behavior that you see? Please describe in detail what you do and what happens at each step.

Comment: 1) I forked repo from github.
2) I imported repo in gitlab.
3) I clonned repo using "git clone `Repo Name`"
4) Boom. No files I have changed. Still all files are showing as "Deleted" to commit.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add that information. Also describe what happened when you performed those steps and what you want to happen instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guys. It was because of long folder path. I cloned it to root of my drive and all path shortened. So Issue resolved. following link helped out.

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/issues/1429

Answer (score 0):

how did you clone it?

```
git clone https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples
```

and then:

```
git status
```

result:

```
On branch release
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/release'.
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

Comment: git status
On branch aspnetcore1
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/aspnetcore1'.

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        deleted:    .gitignore
        deleted:    Clients/Clients4.sln

Comment: what a strange :o
try restore:
git reset HEAD *
git checkout *